# Perturbation method for complex small variable in system of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, perturbation-theory

Consider the following system of ODEs:

$$
i\dot{C_1}(t)=\nu^*(\omega) e^{i(\omega-\omega_{10})t} C_2(t)\\
i\dot{C_2}(t)=\nu(\omega) e^{-i(\omega-\omega_{10})t} C_1(t)
$$
with initial conditions $C_1(0)=1$ and $C_2(0)=0$.

Here $\nu(\omega)\ll1$ so I would like to perform a perturbation solution. But what confuses me is that there is not only $\nu(\omega)$, but also a complex conjugate $\nu^*(\omega)$. They clearly have the same order, but, nevertheless, they are different. Should I look at possible solutions with both of them? Namely,
$$
C_1(t)\approx C_1^0+C_1^1\nu+O(\nu^2)\\
C_2(t)\approx C_2^0+C_2^1\nu+O(\nu^2)
$$

and

$$
C_1(t)\approx C_1^0+C_1^1\nu^*+O(\nu^{*^2})\\
C_2(t)\approx C_2^0+C_2^1\nu^*+O(\nu^{*^2})
$$
? And then see which one stays?

Comment: You could consider the perturbative ansatz $C_1(t)=\sum\limits_n x_n(t)\epsilon^n$, $C_2(t)=\sum\limits_n y_n(t)\epsilon^n$, and add an epsilon to your equations $i\dot{C_1}=\epsilon \nu e^{it(\omega-\omega_0)}C_2$, $i\dot{C_2}=\epsilon \nu^* e^{-it(\omega-\omega_0)}C_1$, then match powers of epsilon order by order.

Comment: Thank you! Makes things work like a piece of cake now!